# Facebook Likes for site don't show thumbnails or meta in news feed

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like, metadata, facebook-opengraph

So I'll be the first to admit I'm not so great with the whole facebook like button thing.

On my site http://vegasonthemic.com I have facebook "like" buttons for every post (of a custom post type "portfolio") that are automagically generated.
When you click this like button it shows on your facebook profile that you liked something with a thumbnail and the excerpt text. 
BUT when you look at your news feed all it says is "Bob liked this artist" and doesn't show any of the metadata. Is there something I'm missing for this function to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can see your problem here:  http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fvegasonthemic.com%2F

Fix the issues that the linter is showing.  Then your website will work fine.